# The Pygame image is not loading up correctly

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a game in PyGame. But when I want to load images, the background image is not loading up correctly. Also, no error message is showing up.

The code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


# Images
icon = pygame.image.load("Images/icon.ico")

background = pygame.image.load("Images/sky.png")
sun = pygame.image.load("Images/sun.png")

# Setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Game loop
running = True

while  running:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sun, (100, 100))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Here's what I got:
[image: link to image]

Comment: I literally copied all your code and tested it out with some images with the same name and same type. It is working properly. The issue might be with the images. Can you show the folder containing the images?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I don't know if there is something wrong with the folder, but here's a screenshot: [link](https://imgur.com/a/FdALNn1)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because you did `pygame.init()` after using `pygame.image.load()`.

Basically it can't load it because it's not initiated yet, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment. Your suggestion doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: I tried it… it didn't solve the problem… :(